# Search&replace closing tag after matching starting tag+any content inside in XML

Tags: text-processing, sed, xml

I'm trying to find the solution for search and replace in WordPress export XML file that will:

1. find string

   ```
   <content:encoded><![CDATA[HERE GOES ANY POSSIBLE POSTS TEXT including HTML tags]]></wp:meta_value>
   ```
2. replace closing tag `</wp:meta_value>` with `</content:encoded>`

The problem is that XML file has lot of other closing `</wp:meta_value>` tags - not only for starting `<content:encoded>`.

Any sed solutions I searched didn't help. Is it doable with any bash commands?

PS: My goal is to convert custom field to the default WP content tag. The original code I need to change is like:

```
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[page_content_0_text]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[POST CONTENT GOES HERE]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
```

And I need:

```
<content:encoded><![CDATA[POST CONTENT GOES HERE]]></content:encoded>
```

`<content:encoded>` is unique for each post in XML and `<wp:postmeta>` is not.

Comment: Use an XML-aware tool, e.g. xmlstarlet or xsh.

Comment: This is a programming, not a unix question. Also, as choroba said, `sed` is the wrong tool to parse XML. I'm not aware of any bash builtins that can parse XML (Pretty certain there are none). But there's certainly quite a few command line tools that can parse XML.

Comment: @choroba.  XML-aware tools expect valid and well-formed XML.  This is not the case here.

Comment: @MarcusMüller No XML parser would parse this text file correctly.

Comment: Did you, by any chance, edit the start tags yourself? Or did you modify the CDATA section so that the tags became unmatched?? If Wordpress exported an XML file with unbalanced tags, you may want to file a bug report against that software.   If you edited this data, then consider posting the _original_ data and let us know in what way you intended to change it.

Comment: Can you post a realistic input file you're working with rather than an oversimplified version?

Comment: Is this string that you want to change multiline or could be multiline or single line ?

Comment: Thank you all for all your comments, I've added some more info on the XML file to the question.

Comment: Kusalananda, yes I was able to edit start tag myself. Thanks.

Comment: `xml2 - convert xml documents in a flat format` - which would be easily interpreted by sed or BASH. `2xml - convert flat format into xml` presumably could do what you want if your file is not too large. Install the xml2 package to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will exploit the property of a `CDATA` section ,viz., that it *cannot* contain the substring `]]>` within it:

```
perl -0777 -pe '
  s{
    <content:encoded>
    <!\[CDATA\[.*?]]> \K
    </wp:meta_value>
  }[</content:encoded>]xgs;
' your_file.input
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks!